# cURL on 10 000 URLs - 500 internal error

Tags: php, curl

I have this awkward issue, my script works, but it fails on huge queries.
I need to crawl each of the external URLs in my database. The idea is to get their response code and if the response code is not satisfying to delete the URL. Here is my code.

```
for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){ 
$url=mysql_result($resultURL, $i );
$massiveArray[] = $url;}

foreach ( $massiveArray as $url) {
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);  
curl_exec($ch); 
$retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch); 

    if ( ($retcode == 200) || ($retcode == 201) || ($retcode == 204) || ($retcode == 300) || ($retcode == 301) || ($retcode == 302)) {

        $countOK += 1;  

            }
            echo  '<a target="_blank" href="'.$url . '">'.$url.'</a> -  OK ' . $retcode . '<br /> ';
    } else {

        $countBAD +=1; 
        echo $url .  ' -  BAD ' . $retcode . '<br />'; 
        mysql_query('DELETE FROM `urls` WHERE `url` = "'.$url.'"');     
    }}
```

I have about 10 000 urls, so I really need to make this happen. I've tried to extend the php execution time and so on, but when the script reach about 100 of checked URLs a 500 internal error occurs.

Comment: do it in chunks, say 100 from the db, loop, next 100

Comment: You're doing a denial of service on yourself.  Slow it down. Pull a url from a db where its not viewed, crawl it, set to viewed.  Sleep. Do it again.

Comment: are they local urls?

Comment: Are you possibly getting a 500 due to the script timing out?

Comment: @developerwjk It seems that you are right, but I just own the database. Actually I have no coding experience and I've managed to do this script on my own to clean the database and I was surprised that it worked :) I have no clue how to do these checks on steps.

Comment: @HalfCrazed I've set the  max_execution_time to : 0 
I guess the timeout is not the problem.

Comment: Check your server logs then to find the problem.

Comment: You can use `usleep` to wait a fractional number of seconds - even a few tenths of a second delay will help.

Comment: Solved. Because the server was unable to handle the requests at once. Maybe some shared hosting time outs triggered or something. I do not know. However, I've added additional field 'crawled' to the database with default value no, so once url was processed. An update query was sent to change crawled from no to yes. By doing this script was able to complete the job in few separate runs.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem too and I have also tried to extend the php execution time but I couldn't see any change.

What I did was, limited the number of queries to 100(in your case it might be another number). This script executed within 1 minute with successful result. Then I ran the "Cron Job" on that script for every 1 minute. In this way, I could complete all the 10,000 URLs.

I know that this is not the best solution but it is a solution.

Hope that helps. Please let me know if you find a better answer.